# Remove An Item In A Listview

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

This seems to be quite easy but I'm having a problem about this right now.

What I want to do is look for a specific entry in the second column of my list view and then if that specific entry if found, remove the row where that entry is found.

Here's my code:

```
      Dim lvSubItems As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem

      For Each lvSubItems In lvConnectedClients.Items(lvConnectedClients.Items.Count - 1).SubItems

            If lvSubItems.Text = CType(clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString Then

                  ' This is not the correct way.
                  lvConnectedClients.Items.Remove(lvSubItems)

            End If

      Next
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 For Each lvSubItems As Object In ListView1.Items
            If lvSubItems.Text = "test" Then
                ListView1.Items.Remove(lvSubItems)
            End If
 Next
```

or

```
For Each lvSubItems As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

        If lvSubItems.SubItems(1).Text = "1" Then
            ListView1.Items.Remove(lvSubItems)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, below works for me (adding the "As ListViewItem"). Let me know.

```
For Each li As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

        If li.Text = "test 7" Then

        ListView1.Items.Remove(li)

        End If

Next
```

My code to create items:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To 9

        Dim li As New ListViewItem("test " & i)


        ListView1.Items.Add(li)


    Next
```